# Creating Multiple MySQL Databases with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Am I doing some thing wrong? I am trying to create 2 databases in a single attempt, and failing.

2 queries > `sql` and `sql1`

My 2nd query `sql1` is running fine and but the 1st query `sql` is giving me error

**Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''int_marks`varchar(3) NULL,`ext_marks`varchar(3) NULL,`total` varchar(3)' at line

**Problem 2**

When I get this error, I am showing an CROSS image. And I want to show the error message when I hover on it. I used it in `title tag` but it's not working.

```
<?php

isset( $_REQUEST['dbname'] ) ? $dbname=$_REQUEST['dbname'] : $dbname='';
$dbname = mysql_real_escape_string( $dbname );
$names = 'names';

if (strlen($dbname) <= 4) {
echo "name/id should contain more than 5 Characters";
} 

else {
include_once("config.php");

$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$createdb` (
  `rollno` varchar(10) NULL,
  `subcode` varchar(10) NULL,
   `subname` varchar(50) NULL,
    'int_marks` varchar(3) NULL,
    `ext_marks` varchar(3) NULL,
    `total` varchar(3) NULL,
    `result` varchar(3) NULL,
    `credits` varchar(3) NULL
);";


$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE `$dbname$names` (
  `bio` varchar(10) NULL,
  `addr` varchar(80) NULL
);";

  if (mysql_query($sql))
  {
  echo "<img scr='img/good.png' title='Database $dbname Created'>";
  }
else
  {
 echo "<img scr='img/bad.png' title='. mysql_error()'>:" . mysql_error();

  }

  if (mysql_query($sql1))
  {
  echo "<img scr='img/good.png' title='Database $dbname Created'>";
  }
else
  {

 echo "<img scr='img/bad.png' title='. mysql_error()'>:" . mysql_error();
  }

} 
?>
```

I WANT TO KNOW ONE MORE THING. is is possible to do this in any other easier way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mismatched quotes (one is a single quote, the other is a backtick)

```
'int_marks`
```

Edit: please get away from mysql, it is deprecated. Use the mysqli API or PDO instead

Comment: The second one is not a quote, it's a backtick. He doesn't need to upgrade from mysql, he just has to use the mysqli API instead of the deprecated mysql API.

Comment: thanks that workes.. i missed it :) and did you know the solution for my PROBLEM 2 > i want to show the mysql error as image title...

Comment: It looks like another quote thing to me, plus you didn't close the img tag properly with a backslash before the closing tag